# audio tag not working in ReactJS application deployed in AWS Amplify

Tags: html, reactjs, aws-amplify

I have a ReactJS application that is deployed in AWS Amplify. The application has two mp3 files to play on certain conditions. They work fine in the localhost but in the deployed one I can't hear anything. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
import ErrorSound from "../../assets/sounds/error.mp3";
import SuccessSound from "../../assets/sounds/success.mp3";

<audio controls={false} autoPlay>
    <source src={props.correct ? SuccessSound : ErrorSound} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: Hey, facing this same issue. Have you managed to find a fix?

Comment: still no @cluelesswaffle

Comment: I could only manage to work it by using an online source, i.e. uploading the mp3 on a S3 bucket.

Comment: thanks for the idea. will try doing this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add an mp3 file extension to your application's URL rewrites in Amplify.

In your app's homepage in Amplify click on 'Rewrites and redirects' under App Settings. Then click edit and add mp3 to the list of extensions in your rewrite rule.

It'll probably look something like this after you add it:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|png|mp3|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```